# Deleting oldest data weekly

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using ELK to create dashboards but I would like to delete frequently data, in fact every minute I get 100 new data and I would like to delete every week the oldest data. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use Curator `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/index.html`

There are several options in Curator to manage your data in the indices, you can delete them after a specific number of days which I believe is what you are looking for. There are also options to delete data based on the disk size if it exceeds a specific threshold.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As he answered @ranjithkr we can use Curator.
For more information: http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2017/04/09/usingcuratordeleteelasticindex.html